# Python Как создать аннотацию на вложенный в функцию класс?

Tags: python, функции, аннотации

У меня есть следующий код:

```
class Rule:
    @property
    def _is_active(self):
        return True

    def __call__(self, func:Callable[[RuleWrapper], bool]):
        class RuleWrapper:
            @property
            def my_value()
                return 123

            def __call__(nested_self, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> Any:
                if self._is_active:
                    return func(nested_self, *args, **kwds)
        
        wrapper = RuleWrapper()
        update_wrapper(wrapper, func)
        return wrapper
```

Как правильно задать аннотацию `func` в `__call__` методе? Сейчас неправильно ссылается на `RuleWrapper`.

---

Добавляю исходный код, если это поможет понять, почему я использую вложенный класс. Если что, вопрос остаётся прежним.

```
class Rule:
    ''' Правило политики управления кэшем. Используйте экземпляр этого класса
         в качестве декоратора ваших функций для декларации поведения кэша.'''

    class Type(IntFlag):
        ''' Тип правила политики. Предназначен для разграничения области применения правила. '''

        ALLOW = auto()
        ''' Разрешающее. Разрешает операцию. '''

        PROCEED = auto()
        ''' Процедурное. Не участвует в принятии решения об операции. '''

        DENY = auto()
        ''' Запрещающее. Запрещает операцию. '''

        GET = auto()
        ''' Получающее. Относится к операции получения объекта из ресурса. '''

        ALLOCATE = auto()
        ''' Выделяющее. Относится к операции выделения ресурса для объекта. '''

        FREE = auto()
        ''' Освобождающее. Относится к операции высвобождения ресурса от объекта. '''

        CHOICE_FOR_DROP = auto()
        ''' Выбирающее. Относится к операции выбора лучшего кандидата на удаление. '''

        EVICT = auto()
        ''' Вытесняющее. Относится к операции вытеснения объектов с истёкшим сроком жизни. '''

        CLEAR = auto()
        ''' Очищающее. Относится к операции полной очистки ресурса. '''
    
    def __init__(self, cache, rule_type, *, is_active=True, priority=0) -> None:
        assert isinstance(rule_type, Rule.Type), \
            f'Parameter type="{rule_type}" is not "Rule.Type".'
        
        assert bool(rule_type & Rule.Type.ALLOW) + bool(rule_type & Rule.Type.PROCEED) + bool(rule_type & Rule.Type.DENY) == 1, \
            'Incorrect combination of rule type of policy. ' + \
            f'Rule must be ONE of ["{Rule.Type.ALLOW.name}",' + \
            f'"{Rule.Type.PROCEED.name}","{Rule.Type.DENY.name}"]'

        self._cache = cache
        self._rule_type = rule_type
        self._is_active = is_active
        self._priority = priority

    def __call__(self, func:Callable[['Rule.RuleWrapper'], bool]):
        class RuleWrapper:            
            def __call__(nested_self, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> Any:
                if self._is_active:
                    return func(nested_self, *args, **kwds)
            
            @property
            def cache(nested_self):
                return self._cache

            @property
            def rule_type(nested_self):
                return self._rule_type
            
            @property
            def priority(nested_self):
                return self._priority
            
            @property
            def is_active(nested_self):
                return self._is_active
            
            def deactivate(nested_self):
                if self._is_active:
                    self._is_active = False
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            
            def activate(nested_self):
                if self._is_active:
                    return False
                else:
                    self._is_active = True
                    return True

        wrapper = RuleWrapper()
        update_wrapper(wrapper, func)
        return wrapper
```

И пример использования

```
# тестовые параметры
capacity = 10
evict_cooldown = 10
fill_factor = 0.75 # 75%

policy = partial(Rule, file_system_storage)

@policy(Rule.Type.PROCEED | Rule.Type.ALLOCATE, priority=1)
def evict_available(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' Задержка перед вытеснением прошла '''
    return (self.cache.last_evict - datetime.utcnow()) > evict_cooldown

@policy(Rule.Type.PROCEED | Rule.Type.ALLOCATE, priority=1)
def is_cache_overflow_close(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' Kэш заполнен больше (или равно), чем на fill_factor процентов '''
    return self.cache.limit.utilization >= fill_factor

@policy(Rule.Type.PROCEED | Rule.Type.ALLOCATE | Rule.Type.GET, priority=0)
def evict_if_require(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
    ''' Вытеснить устаревшие объекты кэша, если требуется '''
    if  evict_available() and is_cache_overflow_close():
        self.cache.evict()

def build_allocate_polycies(storage:CachedResource):
        @policy(Rule.Type.DENY | Rule.Type.ALLOCATE, priority=1)
        def item_gt_half_cache(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
            ''' Объект больше, чем половина кэша '''
            return item.size > (self.cache.limit.capacity / 2)

        @policy(Rule.Type.ALLOW | Rule.Type.ALLOCATE, priority=1)
        def item_lte_cache_free_volume(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
            ''' В кэше достаточно свободного места для объекта '''
            return item.size <= (self.cache.limit.capacity - self.cache.limit.used_volume)

        @policy(Rule.Type.PROCEED | Rule.Type.ALLOCATE, priority=2)
        def force_evict_require(self, *args, **kwargs):
            ''' Требуется немедленно вытеснить устаревшие объекты из кэша '''
            self.cache.evit()

        @policy(Rule.Type.ALLOW | Rule.Type.ALLOCATE, priority=3)
        def free_unexpired_require(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
            ''' Требуется вытеснить неустаревшие объекты из кэша '''

            # в худшем случае мы готовы удалить все объекты из кэша
            while not item_lte_cache_free_volume(item):
                # удаляем лучшего кандидата на удаление
                best_candidate = self.cache.best_drop_candidate
                assert best_candidate is not None, 'Кэш, вероятно, пуст, но места недостаточно. Ошибка построения политик?'
                self.cache.free(best_candidate)
            
            return True
        
        storage.add_policy(evict_if_require)
        storage.add_policy(item_gt_half_cache)
        storage.add_policy(item_lte_cache_free_volume)
        storage.add_policy(force_evict_require)
        storage.add_policy(free_unexpired_require)
```

Comment: Наверное как-то надо `@wraps` использовать, может быть на `__call__` повесить его. Но вообще что-то прям намудрили. Вложенный класс это какое-то излишество.

Comment: @CrazyElf декоратор `@property` работает точно также.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
class Rule:
    @property
    def _is_active(self):
        return True

    def __call__(self, func: Callable[['Rule.RuleWrapper'], bool]):
        class RuleWrapper:
            @property
            def my_value(self):
                return 123

            def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> Any:
                if self._is_active:
                    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
        
        wrapper = RuleWrapper()
        update_wrapper(wrapper, func)
        return wrapper
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! К сожалению, `RuleWrapper` **не разрешается**. Я бы хотел дать подсказку пользователю, что первым аргументом функция `func` должна принимать `RuleWrapper`, а также иметь `*args, **kwds`